# Linear Hypothesis t-Test in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, t-test

Given

```
         x1  | x2  | x3  |  x4
      --------------------------
n     |  73  | 105 | 240 | 1080
mean  | 6.22 | 5.81| 5.77| 5.47
s     |  1.62| 1.43| 1.24| 1.31
```

I am attempting to conduct a hypothesis test for $H_0 : \mu_1 + \mu_2 + \mu_3 - 3\mu_4 = 0$. With the following R code:

```
cont = c(1, 1, 1, -3)
stats = data.frame(n = c(73, 105, 240, 1080), mean = c(6.22, 5.81, 5.77, 5.47), sd = c(1.62, 1.43, 1.24, 1.31))
cont.est <- sum(cont * stats[, 'mean'])
cont.se <- sum(cont * stats['sd'] / sqrt(stats['n']))
k <- length(stats)
cont.t <- cont.est / cont.se
cont.p <- 2 * pt(-abs(cont.t), df=sum(stats[, 'n']) - k)
cont.p

> 1.750107e-06
```

Is this code appropriate for what I am trying to do? If not, what do I need to change?

Comment: "y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 - 3*x4" throws an error for me in R.  Are you missing a lm statement or glm statement perhaps?  Maybe an equal sign?  On closer examination, this doesn't make much sense unless you intend to recycle elements since your vectors are of unequal length.

Comment: It works for me, I'm using R studio if that makes a difference. Not too familiar with R in general though, sorry

Comment: R Studio is just a front end for the R-engine, so that doesn't make much sense.  To verify, I tried this in R Studio, and it fails.  This code will not work.  To be certain, you haven't even assigned anything to the variable y, so how can you even do a t-test on it?  I suspect you have created y previously in your code and that is what you are referencing when you call t.test -- not anything you've shown us here. So this is not doing what you intended it to do.

Comment: There's `library(car)` also

Comment: You're correct, it was set earlier with `y = x1 + x2 + x3 - 3*x4`. I misread the warnings as an error

Comment: OK.  Thanks or editing the main post.  Do you also intend to recycle the elements of 'x1', 'x2', and 'x3'?  I wouldn' think so, but that's what you are doing.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm trying to do the hypothesis test described, the code was my best guess but I wouldn't be surprised if it was quite far off

Comment: It looks like you are intending build some sort of linear model and then test the contrasts provided.  But what you've done is nothing of the sort.  If this is for school work, I suggest you re-read the material and try to work through this or visit your instructor for some guidance.

Comment: @StatsStudent thanks for the advice. I'd missed a handout that was quite helpful. I've updated the code accordingly if you'd like to take another look